# Foxid Reader for Ubuntu opens all file types, file type association bug?

Tags: pdf, foxitreader

I use [Foxid Reader for Ubuntu](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/), but there is a bug where all file types get opened with it. The file type association is linked to any existing extension. It is really annoying to have to unset every single file type every time I have to open it, becaus it causes an error when openning non PDF files:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Foxid installer has a bug and misunderstands the file type association configurations.

Open a Terminal (with Ubuntu press Ctrl + Alt + T), then open the ~/.local/share/applications folder with the Change Directory comand:

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
```

Open the FoxidReader.desktop file:

```
nano FoxidReader.desktop
```

And inside the Nano text editor, remove the highlighted following command like this:
[image]

Such that you are left as this:

[image]

Press Ctrl + X to save, and enter Yes when prompted.

Then, inside the same folder, edit mimeapps.list:

```
nano mimeapps.list
```

Originally, this file is like this,
[image]

Comment the last line, because FoxitReader does not support application/octet-stream. You should get it as this:

[image]

Press Ctrl + X to save again and you are done.

The bug is posted in [here](http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/158735-anoying-fixable-bug-in-foxit-reader-for-linux).